# Bootstrap navbar disappears using leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, conflict, leaflet

I am having some difficulty integrating leaflet with Bootstrap. I am using a script that creates a collapsible left navbar. When I interact with the leaflet map, the bootstrap navbar disappears.

This seems to be a CSS conflict, but I can't seem to identify where to begin troubleshooting. Here is the jsfiddle followed by CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/6sSrE/. Notice that when clicking the map, the navbar disappears.

It would be helpful if another set of eyes could suggest a different direction to identify this problem. I would really like to use Bootstrap for this application, but I can't resolve the conflict.

```
html, body, #map {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
   body .viewport {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .viewport .frame {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

body .viewport .frame .navbar .navbar-inner {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 5px; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu {
  height: 100%;
  /* background-color: #3D6AA2; */ 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu.collapse {
  float: left;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu.collapse.height {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  transition: height 0.35s ease; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu.collapse.width {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  transition: width 0.35s ease; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu.collapse.in.width {
  width: auto; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu.collapse.in.height {
  height: auto; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu .collapse-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu .navbar .navbar-inner {
  text-align: center;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 38px; 
}

body .viewport .frame .menu .nav-stacked {
  padding: 0 10px; 
}

body .viewport .frame .view {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

body .viewport .frame .view .navbar .navbar-inner .btn-navbar {
  display: block;
  float: left; 
}

body .viewport .frame .view #map {
  margin: auto 15px;
  text-align: justify; 
}
```

Comment: Here is some relevant conversation on this issue: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like every time the map gets focused the webpage is moving 78 pixels down.  (You might be able to find where this is happening and fix it.)

However I just came up with something quick that would adjust your navbar so that it would show up at the top of the page every time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var margin = 78;
    $('#map').on('mousedown',function(){
        $('#navBar').css('margin-top',margin+'px');
    });  
    $('#map').blur(function(){
        margin = margin+78;
    }); 
});
```

Note: I also added a ID to your nav bar.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="navBar">
```

Here is an example, seems to work pretty good for now, but might be worth your time later to figure out why the page is being moved down.

http://jsfiddle.net/6sSrE/15/

Comment: Looks like this is a little more complicated then that if you click on the menu and then back to the map again it disappears..  Let me see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I've been looking at it for a while, so it is very helpful to have another perspective. I disabled jquery, and it looks like it's something within Leaflet that's changing the css.

Comment: Oops - missed it. Thank you! This works. I will continue to investigate why it was doing that later on.

Comment: It looks as though the <div id="map" /> is inheriting classes related to the bootstrap collapse menu. When viewing with Chrome developer tools, after stripping the #map div of those bootstrap classes (originally, body .viewport .frame .view #map), the navbar still disappears, but resetting the #map's height property in Developer Tools solves the problem. Still can't get it to do this on the first go, however. Additionally, this isn't a problem in Firefox. Could it be related to webkit?

Comment: Last comment - I found a workaround that doesn't rely on jquery. I don't understand why Leaflet is behaving this way, however, I created a new div element (#content) that wraps around the #map div. Setting #content to height: 100% and #map to height: 90% seems to fix the problem. Clicking the map does not trigger the map to move & push the navbar out of the screen. Setting #map to 100% does the same thing.

Comment: Great, i'm glad to hear you found another solution .  Best of luck with your project.